# CentOS how to update ANT Version to 1.8.x or higher?

Tags: apache, ant, centos, repository, yum

I'm using CentOS v6.5 and installed `Ant` by using:

```
yum install ant
```

But it came with `Ant version 1.7.1`. And i need the latest `Ant version 1.8.0`.

- How to properly get the latest `Ant version 1.8.x` (or higher) from `YUM` or anyway please?

Comment: The Redhat and Debian packages often lag well behind the source projects. Either wait, or install the code yourself. Setting up ANT is not hard.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the [Ant Download](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi) site?